# Как оформить предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Другое,  на  что  следует  обратить  внимание, при  такой  схеме  давление  рабочей  среды  в  любом  положении  не  разжимает,  а  сжимает  подвижный  и  неподвижный  элементы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Другое, на что следует обратить внимание: при такой схеме давление рабочей среды в любом положении не разжимает, а сжимает подвижный и неподвижный элементы...

Вторая часть предложения поясняет первую, раскрывая её содержание, поэтому двоеточие. Двоеточие поглощает запятую, закрывающую придаточное.